# LocalWalletNotAvailableError : This error is showing even though site is connected to metamask

Tags: authentication, blockchain, solidity, web3js, metamask

I have implemented a blockchain based authentication using the code from geekforgeeks but When clicking signup button on my code it shows the following error.

```
Invalid value given "LocalWalletNotAvailableError". Error: Attempted to index account in local wallet, but no wallet is available.
LocalWalletNotAvailableError: Invalid value given "LocalWalletNotAvailableError". Error: Attempted to index account in local wallet, but no wallet is available.
```

The account data and netwotk id are loaded correctly but after clicking the sign up button the above mentioned error is shown.
i have copied this code from geeksforgeeeks. this is the web3 helper file code.this the link to the geekforgeeks blog [text](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/build-a-authentication-using-blockchain/) my code for web3helper.js file and Signup.js file are shown.

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import Auth from "./build/contracts/Auth.json";

export const loadWeb3 = async () => {
  console.log("Loading web3");
  if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    console.log("Web3 loading to window.ethereum");
    try {
      console.log("Requesting account access");
      // Request account access if needed
      await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      console.log("Account access granted");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('User denied account access:', error);
    }
  } else if (window.web3) {
    console.log("Web3 loading to window.web3");
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    console.log("Web3 loaded to window.web3");
  } else {
    console.log("Non-Ethereum browser detected");
    window.alert(
      "Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!"
    );
  }
};

export const loadBlockchainData = async () => {
  console.log("Loading blockchain data");
  const web3 = window.web3;
  // Load account
  console.log("Loading accounts");
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log("Accounts loaded");

  // Network ID
  console.log("Loading network ID");
  const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
  console.log("Network ID loaded");

  // Network data
  console.log("Loading network data");
  if (networkId) {
    const auth = new web3.eth.Contract(
      Auth.abi,
      Auth.networks[networkId].address
    );
    console.log("Network data loaded");
    console.log("Returning auth and accounts");
    return { auth, accounts: accounts[0] };
  }
};
```

this the sign up page code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { loadBlockchainData, loadWeb3 } from "../Web3helpers";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SignUp() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState(null);
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadWeb3();
    loadAccounts();
  }, []);

  const loadAccounts = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Loading accounts");
      const { auth, accounts } = await loadBlockchainData();
      console.log("Accounts and auth data loaded");
      setAccounts(accounts);
      setAuth(auth);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading accounts:", error);
    }
  };

  const signUp = async () => {
    console.log("Sign up button clicked");
    if (!username || !email || !password) {
      alert("Please fill in all details");
      return;
    }

    // const mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    // if (!email.match(mailformat)) {
    //   alert("Please enter a valid email address");
    //   return;
    // }

    try {
      if (!auth) {
        throw new Error("Authentication contract not loaded");
      }
      console.log("auth checked");

      if (!accounts || !accounts.length) {
        throw new Error("No accounts loaded");
      }
      console.log("accounts checked");
      await auth.methods
        .createUser(username, email, password)
        .send({ from: accounts[0] });
      console.log("User created");
      localStorage.setItem("username", username);
      localStorage.setItem("email", email);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error signing up:", error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={rootDiv}>
      <img
        src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20210318103632/gfg.png"
        style={image}
        alt="geeks"
      />
      <input
        style={input}
        value={username}
        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Username"
        type="text"
      />
      <input
        style={input}
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Email"
        type="text"
      />
      <input
        style={input}
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Password"
        type="password"
      />
      <button style={button} onClick={signUp}>
        Sign Up
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootDiv = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  height: "100vh",
};

const input = {
  width: 300,
  padding: 10,
  margin: 10,
  borderRadius: 10,
  outline: "none",
  border: "2px solid grey",
  fontSize: 17,
};

const button = {
  width: 325,
  padding: 10,
  borderRadius: 10,
  margin: 10,
  cursor: "pointer",
  fontSize: 17,
  color: "white",
  backgroundColor: "#9D27CD",
  border: "none",
};

const image = {
  width: 70,
  height: 70,
  objectFit: "contain",
  borderRadius: 70,
};
```

i have tried to console log every step this the screenshot of the logs in the console. What did i do wrong?